# Where should I place jQuery Mobile pages generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know the best place to add the HTML code for jQuery Mobile pages that have been dynamically generated?

I have been adding them to the end of the `<body>`, however, this is causing problems with other jQuery mobile pages.

I have tried adding the jQuery Mobile pages into a div at the end of the page, however, their ids are no longer accessible via `href`s.

Link to Code: http://jakeserver.com/Apps/BostonLandmarks/B11/index.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Body is correct. What are the problems you are seeing on other pages after adding the new pages?

Comment: @ezanker I tried to add in a Google map, where JS created html and put it inside a div. The map container does not display unless the pages that are at the bottom of the <body> are commented out. All of it validates. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't suppose you could recreate the issue in a jsFiddle?

Comment: @ezanker Would you mind if I posted the link to the HTML and JS file (it may look confusing in JS fiddle)?

Comment: @ezanker I have added the link to the post. If you click on it, and navigate to the map screen, you will see it blank; however, when the "assembleLandmarkPages" function is not called (in landmarks.js) the map appears fine. Any ideas?

Comment: I have created a fiddle that seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6w7q7/. I took all the script you had within pages and moved it to the 'pagecreate' event of the page.  Have a look at the fiddle and see if this works for you.

Comment: @ezanker Thank you very much. That fiddle works perfectly. Do you know why it has to be enclosed within the pageShow function?

Comment: Using the page events ensures that the code runs at the correct time with respect to jQM's page creation, etc. Have a look at http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: @ezanker Sorry, I hit the wrong button. Thank you very much for your help. I will read the article. If you move your comment to an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you move all script within the individual page divs to a global script tag and then run that code within a pagecreate event of the page e.g.:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate','#landmarks', function(){
    function setNewActiveTab(newTab){
        $(".LandmarksTab").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
        $(".LandmarksTab").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
        $(".MoreTab").removeClass("ui-btn-active");
        $(newTab).addClass("ui-btn-active");
    }

    assembleRows(landmarksArray);
    assembleLandmarkPages(landmarksArray);
    determineMapScreen();
});
```

> Here is a working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/6w7q7/)** based on your code.

This will ensure that the code runs at the correct time with respect to jQM's page creation/enhancement.